# Why is my django-channels project not able to connect to Websockets in my Heroku deployed site?

Tags: django, heroku, websocket, redis, django-channels

I've been stuck at this for daaaays now and I realise that solution is probably simple but I no matter how much I read here and try I get the same error... When loading the chats part of my site I get this error in the dev tools console:

`WebSocket connection to 'wss://vareberg-games-a44cb52aa87b.herokuapp.com/wss/chat/' failed:  (anonymous) @ chats/:131`

and line 131 in the chats.html is inside the script tags and looks like this:

`const chatSocket = new WebSocket('wss://' + window.location.host + '/wss/chat/');`

This is all the files I think are relevant to get help:

The projects settings.py file:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import dj_database_url
if os.path.isfile('env.py'):
    import env

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['vareberg-games-a44cb52aa87b.herokuapp.com', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'daphne',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'profiles',
    'events',
    'channels',
    'chats',
]

SITE_ID = 1

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
'signup': 'profiles.forms.CustomSignupForm',
}
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'allauth.account.middleware.AccountMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'varberggames.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'varberggames.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.parse(os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL"))
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Stockholm'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'productionfiles'

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# Daphne
ASGI_APPLICATION = "varberggames.asgi.application"
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": "redis-13025.c268.eu-west-1-2.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com:13025",
        },
    },
}
```

the projects asgi.py file:

```
import os
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

import chats.routing
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'varberggames.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": django_asgi_app,
    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            chats.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

the chats apps views.py file:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Chat, Message
from django.db.models import Q

def chats_view(request):
    # Retrieve a list of chat conversations that the logged-in user is a part of
    user = request.user
    chat_conversations = Chat.objects.filter(users=user)

    context = {
        'chat_conversations': chat_conversations,
    }

    return render(request, 'chats.html', context)
def user_search(request):
    search_query = request.GET.get("search_query", "")
    users = User.objects.filter(
        Q(username__icontains=search_query)
        | Q(first_name__icontains=search_query)
        | Q(last_name__icontains=search_query)
    ).values("id", "username", "first_name", "last_name")

    return JsonResponse({"users": list(users)})


def fetch_chat_history(request):
    user_id = request.GET.get("user_id")
    # Implement a query to retrieve chat history with the selected user
    messages = Message.objects.filter(
    Q(sender=request.user, receiver_id=user_id) | Q(sender_id=user_id, receiver=request.user)).order_by('timestamp')

    chat_history = []
    for message in messages:
        chat_history.append({
            'content': message.content,
            'sender_id': message.sender_id,
        })

    return JsonResponse({'messages': chat_history})
```

Chats apps consumers.py file:

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        user_id = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['user_id']
        self.user = self.scope["user"]  # The current user
        self.target_user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)  # The user you are chatting with

        if self.user.is_authenticated and self.user != self.target_user:
            # Check if the current user is authenticated and not chatting with themselves
            self.chat_group_name = f"chat_{self.user.id}_with_{self.target_user.id}"

            await self.channel_layer.group_add(
                self.chat_group_name,
                self.channel_name
            )
            await self.accept()
        else:
            await self.close()
            await self.accept()

        async def disconnect(self, close_code):
            await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.chat_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']
        user = self.scope["user"]  # Get the user who sent the message

        # Handle incoming messages
        if user.is_authenticated:
            await self.channel_layer.group_send(
                self.chat_group_name,
                {
                    'type': 'chat_message',
                    'message': message,
                    'username': user.username,
                }
            )

    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']
        username = event['username']

        # Send the message to the WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message,
            'username': username,
        }))
```

Chats apps models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Chat(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='chats')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sent_messages')
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='received_messages')
    content = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.sender.username} to {self.receiver.username}: {self.content}"
```

Chats apps routing.py file:

```
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.urls import path
from chat.consumers import ChatConsumer

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': URLRouter([
        path('wss/chat/<str:user_id>/', ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
    ])
})
```

Chats apps urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("user_search/", views.user_search, name="user_search"),
    path('chats/', views.chats_view, name='chats'),
    path('fetch_chat_history/', views.fetch_chat_history, name='fetch_chat_history'),
]
```

and finally the chats.html template that is trying to connect to the websockets:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="d-flex container justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <input type="text" id="user-search" class="custom-textarea"
                                placeholder="Search for users...">
                            <button class="btn signupbtn orange-btn" id="search-button" type="button">Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="search-results-container">
                <ul id="search-results">
                    <!-- Search results will be added here dynamically -->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex container justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <h1>Chat List</h1>
            <ul>
                {% for chat in chat_conversations %}
                <li><a href="#" class="chat-link" data-chat-id="{{ chat.id }}">{{ chat.name }}</a></li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="chat-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Chat</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="chat-messages">
                    <!-- Chat messages will be displayed here -->
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" id="message-input" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a message">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="send-button">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% block page_scripts %}
<script>
    const chatSocket = new WebSocket('wss://' + window.location.host + '/wss/chat/');

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Handle user search and initiate a chat
        function searchAndInitiateChat() {
            var searchInput = $("#user-search");
            var searchQuery = searchInput.val();

            // Send a request to the server to search for users
            $.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'user_search' %}",
                method: "GET",
                data: { search_query: searchQuery },
                success: function (data) {
                    var resultsContainer = $("#search-results");
                    resultsContainer.empty();

                    if (data.users.length > 0) {
                        var users = data.users;
                        for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                            var user = users[i];
                            var userItem = $("<li></li>");
                            userItem.text(user.username + " (" + user.first_name + " " +      user.last_name + ")");
                            userItem.attr("data-user-id", user.id);

                            // Add "Start Chat" button
                            var startChatButton = $("<button class='btn start-chat-button orange-btn'>Start Chat</button>");
                            startChatButton.attr("data-user-id", user.id);
                            userItem.append(startChatButton);

                            resultsContainer.append(userItem);
                        }

                        // Handle user selection and chat initiation
                        resultsContainer.on("click", ".start-chat-button", function () {
                            var userId = $(this).parent().data("user-id");

                            // Perform the chat initiation logic
                            initiateChat(userId);

                            // Clear the search input
                            searchInput.val("");
                            resultsContainer.empty();
                        });
                    } else {
                        resultsContainer.html("<p>No users found.</p>");
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        // Handle search button click
        $("#search-button").on("click", function () {
            searchAndInitiateChat();
        });

        // Handle Enter key press in the search input
        $("#user-search").on("keypress", function (e) {
            if (e.which === 13) {
                searchAndInitiateChat();
            }
        });

        function initiateChat(userId) {
            // Dynamically generate the WebSocket URL with the selected user's ID
            var chatSocketURL = 'wss://' + window.location.host + '/wss/chat/' + userId + '/';

            // Open the chat modal
            $('#chat-modal').modal('show');

            // Fetch chat messages using AJAX and display in the modal
            $.ajax({
                url: "{% url 'fetch_chat_history' %}",
                method: "GET",
                data: { user_id: userId },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#chat-messages').empty();

                    if (data.messages.length > 0) {
                        $.each(data.messages, function (index, message) {
                            displayChatMessage(message);
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

            // Set up a WebSocket connection with the dynamically generated URL
            var chatSocket = new WebSocket(chatSocketURL);

            chatSocket.onmessage = function (e) {
                var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
                displayChatMessage(data);
            }
        }

        // Function to display chat messages
        function displayChatMessage(message) {
            var chatMessages = $("#chat-messages");
            chatMessages.append("<p>" + message.sender + ": " + message.content + "</p>");
        }

        // Handle send button click to send a new message
        $("#send-button").on("click", function () {
            var messageInput = $("#message-input");
            var message = messageInput.val().trim();
            if (message) {
                // Send the message via the existing WebSocket connection
                chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
                    'message': message
                }));
                messageInput.val("");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

I have connected it to Redis Add on in heroku, and I put the Redis endpoint url and password in my heroku config vars.
If there is any more info needed please let me know and all help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

I have tried to change the routing.py file to a set url(my projects deployed url..) and changed the  script for the websocket to dynamically get the correct websocket url or set a staic one, I still get the errors.. i was expecting it to connect so my chat app would be functioning.